How to programmatically create an alias projection?
I'm dealing with a dynamically typed document. I want to programmatically create an alias projection, similar to:
$project:
{
    ["alias"]: "name"
}

If the document were statically typed, I can achieve this by using a lambda expression:
Builders<Entity>.Projection.Expression(e => new { alias = e.name })

However since in my case the alias can only be determined in the runtime (and it can even contain characters that are not allowed in an identifier, such as .), I can't build an expression out of it. I can do:
Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name" /* how to "as alias"? */)

but obviously I can't give it an alias.

What do you really want to do here? Deserialise some BSON?

If you need expression in runtime, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/expression-trees-building, but you also can use query in BsonDocument form, instead Builder, see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/faq/#why-are-certain-linq-or-builder-expressions-unsupported- some examples

@YungDeiza we are trying to allow the user to define the schema.

I've solved this by implementing a custom ProjectionDefinition:
public sealed class AliasFieldProjectionDefinition<TSource>(string alias, string name)
    : ProjectionDefinition<TSource>
{
    public override BsonDocument Render(
        IBsonSerializer<TSource> sourceSerializer,
        IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry,
        LinqProvider linqProvider)
    {
        var fieldDefinition = new StringFieldDefinition<TSource>(alias);
        var renderedField = fieldDefinition.Render(sourceSerializer, serializerRegistry, linqProvider);
        return new BsonDocument(renderedField.FieldName, new BsonString(name));
    }
}

And...
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
    .Project(new AliasFieldProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument>(alias, name);



you don't need this. You can just use .Project(new BsonDocument("", ""))
